How not to loose over 90% Android app users with the new Sdk version (Android 14)?

I wanted to upload my app bundle to App Store, but the Android version was not enough (has to be at least 14);
I updated my app updating SDK from 33 to 34 and kept minSdkVersion 21 - resulting an error: minimum Sdk version has to be at least 33;
Updated minimum Sdk version to 33 and was able to upload my app bundle to App Store.
Since that high Sdk version referres to Android 14, App Store shows me a warning that I will loose over 90% of my app users.

How not to loose that many users and let them still use new, fixed and updated versions of my app?


Details about "error: minimum Sdk version has to be at least 33" would be more informative along with what library/frameworks/permissions you are using.

You're mistaken in what SDK version you changed.  There's minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion.  The play store requires you to have the targetSDKVersion to be at least 14, but the minimum can be as low as you want.  So change the minSDKVerion back and adjust the targetSDKVersion instead.
The difference between the two-  the minSDKVersion is the lowest version of Android your app will run on.  The targetSDKVersion is the version you're targetting.  Changing that changes how some APIs behave, they will keep legacy behavior if your targetSDKVersion is older.

Thank you! This answer was more clear to me: to just set the min or target versions appropriately. Though because of some plugins my minSDKVersion has to be 16 instead of 14. I was able to set the targetSDKVersion to 35.

You might be confusing the SDK version with the Android version.  The Play Store requires apps to be compiled with the latest SDK version, which is currently SDK version 34. This means your compile Sdk and target Sdk should be set to 34.  The minimum Sdk version must be at least 23, as that's a requirement for using SDK 34 (You can refer here)

I set the minSDKVersion to 16 and targetSDKVersion to 35 - this worked
